# Use of uninitialized value in array value

Tags: arrays, perl, indexing

I am having an array named @Lst_1. One of my elements is 0 in array.
Whenever I call that element. In example below the value stored in second index of an array is 0.

```
$Log_Sheet->write(Row,0,"$Lst_1[2]",$Format);
```

I am getting a warning saying

> Use of uninitialized value within @Lst_1 in string.

Please help me do that.

Comment: It means there is nothing at `$Lst_1[2]` (third element of `@Lst_1` is `undef` or you don't even have three elements). The "_in string_" part of the warning is because `$Lst_1[2]` is evaluated under quotes -- which you probably don't need.

Comment: Hi zdim, The array has three elements. $Lst_1[2] is having 0 as its value.

Comment: Then the error is not from the expression `"$Lst_1[2]"` itself, since a 0 is a fine value to use there; the error you got specifically means that an undefined variable is being evaluated.  Perhaps the error comes from inside the `write` method?  Also, I can's see how that literal string `Row` may appear just like that; does some module define it?  There is just not enough information altogether.

Answer (score 0):

First index of array is 0. Second element will be `$List_1[1];`

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use v5.22;
use warnings;

my @array = qw(foo bar);

# number of elements in array
say scalar(@array);

# last index of array
say $#array;

# undefined element (warn)
say $array[ $#array + 1];
```

Comment: Hi k-mx, There are three elements in the array. And Lst_1[2] is having 0 as its value.  Whenever I tried to fetch the value of Lst_1[2] it is showing the error.

Comment: I need full source and error message to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to silence the error,

```
$Log_Sheet->write(Row, 0, $Lst_1[2] // 0, $Format);
```

This does use a feature of perl 5.10, but that's ancient enough you really should be using a sufficiently new perl to have it.  I mean, there's a lot of ancient perl bugs, so it behooves you to be using a newer version.

As far as understanding the issue, no, $Lst_1[2] doesn't contain a 0.  It contains an undef, which just happens to be treated mostly like 0 in numeric contexts.

Yes, I did remove the quotes around $Lst_1[2] - that was necessary, because `"$Lst_1[2]"` treats that undef like a string, so it's become the empty string for the purpose of a `"$Lst_1[2]" // 0` test.  (The empty string also happens to be treated like 0, so that doesn't change the behavior in a numeric context.)

It's not clear from your short excerpt whether @Lst_1 is less than 3 elements long, or if there's an explicit undef in @Lst_1.  You'd need to show a larger excerpt of your code - or possibly even the whole thing and the data it is processing - for us to be able to determine that by looking.  You could determine it, however, by adding something like the following in front of the line you gave:

```
if (@Lst_1 < 3) {
    print "\@Lst_1 only has " . @Lst_1 . " elements\n"
} elsif (not defined($Lst_1[2])) {
    print "\$Lst_1[2] is set to undef\n";
}
```

There are two basic ways a list can have an explicit undef element in it.  The following code demonstrates both:

```
my @List = map "Index $_", 0 .. 3;
$List[2] = undef;
$List[5] = "Index 5";

use Data::Dump;
dd @List;
```

This will output

```
("Index 0", "Index 1", undef, "Index 3", undef, "Index 5")
```

The first undef was because I set it, the second was because there wasn't a fifth element but I put something in the sixth slot.